# How should I use "passive-aggressive" as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

How should I use "passive-aggressive" as an adverb? My hunch is that this is correct:

> Jack passive-aggressively said nothing.

What I consider incorrect:

> Jack passively-aggressively said nothing.
>
> Jack passively-aggressive said nothing.

Comment: Is it really necessary to say _passively-aggressively_ instead of _passively and aggressively_?

Comment: "passive-aggressive" refers to a very specific subset of behavior that is not embodied in the non-hyphenated "passive and aggressive" form.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: passive-aggressive is a compound noun with a specific meaning.  The adverb formed from it doesn't split up like that.

Comment: @Rhodri: That is _passive-aggressive_; I don't think the related adverb _passively-aggrassively_ has been ever used.

Comment: @Rhodri: actually, I don't think it's a noun!

Comment: Hmm.  OK, adjective then (I'm busy, that's my excuse).  The point is that whether _passive-aggressively_ has ever been used or not, it would differ in meaning from _passively and aggressively_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that in other similar formations you only inflect the final word (nobody says something "selfly-conscious", for example), I think "passive-aggressively" is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Ah, there we go. I was having trouble finding a similar word. Is there another word with adjectives on both sides of the hyphen? The only examples I can think of are things like "blue-gray."

Comment: @MrHen: There are plenty where the first adjective applies to the second, though use of the hyphen varies. *Small-minded man*, *double-barrelled name*, and *upper-class accent* might be examples.

Answer (score 0):

Correct or not (and for what it's worth I think you're right), it is pretty horrid.  I'd suggest rephrasing to use something more natural.

Comment: Oh, sure. I was mostly curious about the technical aspect of the word.