# "Environmentally-friendly" vs. "Environment-friendly"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, differences

"Environmentally-friendly" sounds completely normal to me. So does "Environment-friendly". But I'm pretty sure I favour the former (despite the fact that I normally prefer the shorter of any two equivalent terms).

According to Google, I'm in good company. At least, the 'allies' massively outnumber those who say "Environment-friendly".

Why is this? *Environment* seems like a straightforward noun. All the other *-friendly* constructions I can think of just bolt on to the uninflected noun...

*User-friendly software*, *Gay-friendly bar*, *Dolphin-friendly tuna*, etc.

I hesitate to ask "What's so special about the environment?", but there it is being asked.

Later... Note that my focus is on why the inflected form apparently 'just happens' to be used with *environment*, but not with other nouns.

Comment: It wouldn't be the only irregularity in English . . . to be: I am, you are, he is, we are, you are, they are, I was, you were, he was, we were, you were, they were . . .

Comment: Whether it's a general rule or not, the hyphen is not commonly used with the sequence of words _environmentally friendly_, whereas it is typically used with the sequence _environment friendly_.

Comment: I'd say mild, warm, clean mediterrean countries are environmentally friendly for the tourists...

Comment: There aren't all that many compound adjectives of the [ADV + ADJ] form, and far fewer still where the adjective is not participial. brightly-lit / well-mannered / hard-working / deeply-rooted / densely-populated / well- ... / ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think there’s anything grammatically wrong with *environment friendly*. It sounds a little funny only because we hear *environmentally friendly* so much more often, and I think the reason for that is historical.

The *environmentally* phrases all seem to have taken off at around the same time, during the 1970s, according to [Google n-grams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=environmentally+sound%2Cenvironmentally+friendly%2Cenvironmentally+responsible%2Cenvironmentally+sensitive%2Cenvironmentally+conscious&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0). The most common of the phrases at that time was *environmentally sound*.

Note that *environment sound* is not an option. It’s clearly ungrammatical, I guess because *sound* doesn’t take any kind of complement: *policies that are sound to the environment* is wrong.

The less common phrases apparently followed the lead of *environmentally sound*, and that’s where we are today.

Comment: Well, I can only give one upvote to your answer, but I have to say it looks pretty convincing to me. *The environment* became more of an issue to forward-thinkers thru the 70's and 80's, but marketing departments only really started pushing their products' "green" credentials in the last couple of decades. By the time they got on the bandwagon, *responsible*, *sensitive*, *concious*, etc., had already staked out the lexical territory. Most of those earlier conjunctives required *-ally* anyway, so the ad-men were just going with the tide of linguistic history...

Comment: @FumbleFingers *“Well, I can only give one upvote to your answer”* Actually, since you asked the question, you can also click the green check mark to select this answer. (Afterwards, if you change your mind, you can select a different answer.) If you don’t select an answer, then on Saturday, the bounty will go to the top-voted answer.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't around to award you the bounty. Let the record state that I do *not* endorse Matthias's attempts to draw semantic distinctions between the two expressions. I'm convinced the truth is more to be found in the answers by yourself and mfe.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that it's not that you're being friendly to the environment. It's that you're being friendly in an environmental way. It's actually odd for me to see the dash in "environmentally-friendly", because the first word in the pair is simply the adverb explaining in what way you are being friendly.

This is probably also informed by the fact that your "environment" can be any number of things from your immediate surroundings up, but "environmental" as an adjective pretty much always refers to something that takes care of "The Environment". We call conservationists "environmentalists", not "environmentists". When you're "environmentally aware", you're aware of how your actions affect The Environment and are aware of ways to minimize your damages. When you're "environment-aware", you simply are aware of your surroundings- that is a term I see passed around my school's computer science labs concerning their robots.

Comment: +1; I don't think the hyphen helps "environmentally-friendly". See also my older question about [passive-aggressive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/how-should-i-use-passive-aggressive-as-an-adverb).

Comment: Agreed; hyphens aren't needed to attach an adverb to the adjective that follows it--it's assumed that the adverb is modifying the adjective. It's needed in "environment-friendly", however, to explicitly tie the noun to the following adjective, as an abbreviation of "friendly towards its environment."

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is because *environmentally* lends itself to other familiar applications; *-friendly* seems to be one of many.  I can think of a few others: environmentally safe, environmentally conscious, environmentally sound, all of which I would consider to be "set phrases", so to speak.

It is worth noting that *gay* may also be used as an adverb as-is, but you've got me at *user-* and *dolphin-*.

Comment: I only put the *gay* one in to humour a gay friend who remembers the old days when gays would be well advised to check such attitudes before ordering a pint and settling down. Today's youngsters would probably think it's a bit like talking about *drinker-friendly* bar. "Wow! - is it *really*? We really must go and check it out!".

Comment: I’m not aware of adverb variants for _user_ and _dolphin_, but it’s not a simple matter of the adverb form being preferred.  (Of course, you didn't say it was.)  Consider _government-friendly_ and _governmentally-friendly_, where the Google popularity test favors the first construction.

Comment: Also, note that _environment safe_ and _environmentally safe_ follow the same pattern.

Comment: *“gay may also be used as an adverb as-is”* Could you give an example?

Comment: @Jason: The adverb is "gaily", and it is associated with the *original* meaning (cheerful, happy-go-lucky) of the adjective "gay".

Answer (score 3):

I am Australian and Environment-friendly sounds wrong to me, I can't recall ever hearing it in common speech. However a google search revealed several reputable sources using it, including an [Australian Government information page.](http://australia.gov.au/topics/family-home-and-community/environment-friendly-products)

Wikipedia redirects "Environment Friendly" to "Environmentally Friendly" and points out "eco-friendly" as a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, there is no easy adverb replacement for *gay-friendly*, *user-friendly* or *dolphin-friendly*, whereas *environmentally friendly* is easily derived from the adjective *environmental*.

I offer no evidence to the following, but there may also be a cadence-preference to separate stress in syllables. Consider *enVIRonMENTally friendly* vs. *enVIRonMENT-friendly*.

Comment: I agree that there is a nicer rhythm/meter to the first but I think there is only one stressed syllable in _environment_.

Comment: @z7sg: I was thinking primary and secondary stress. I didn't know how to denote it cleanly – perhaps as en2viron1mentally and en1viron2ment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say for me "Environmentally friendly" implies a chemical or product that can be mixed or leech into water or nature in general.

```
Lead paint is not environment friendly.
```

Something that is not principally a solution or spray but may be an annoyance or danger might be labelled "Environment friendly".

```
Putting a nail in bathroom is not environment friendly because it could be stepped on.
```

Answer (score 0):

The source for this construction in American speech is typically marketing-driven. Advertisers look very hard for words that have no legal implications but a lot of popular appeal. Hyphenated constructions, under certain fairness-in-advertising rules, are allowed as words which bring no specific social obligation to them.

For example, we went through a time of "-fresh" words, particularly in the late 90's. Fish was ocean-fresh, salads were garden-fresh, eggs were farm-fresh...you get the idea.

The "-friendly" construction is the same game. You can say you are ocean-friendly, garden-friendly, farm-friendly. The terms might resonate who takes such expressions at face value.

Comment: What you say may very well be true, but I didn't ask about *-friendly*. I'm interested to know why in this particular case we mostly precede it by *environmentally*, rather than just *environment*, following the pattern of similar constructions as given in OP.

Comment: When you start seeing "environment-friendly" on any number of American products, you'll see my point. Sorry you didn't find this helpful.

Comment: I *did* find your answer helpful (and interesting), even though it didn't directly address my question, as I said before. It reminded me that the primary users of this expression are in fact ad-men. So unless anyone convinces me otherwise, I'm up for Jason Orendorff's answer. The ad-men took *environmentally sound* from existing usage by Green campaigners, and combined it with up-and-coming *user-friendly* from computer geeks entering mainstream society. Thus was born their buzzword for the new millenium.

Answer (score 0):

Both *Environment-friendly* and *Environmentally-friendly* are not only correct, but in fact required, so they're both bound to show up on google.

It's like this:

Where the packaging is for a product that involves a further assemblage / process / is in the DIY category- like an aerosol spray can of paint, for example- the usage *environmentally-friendly* is good. This here means *Using this product or kit according to the recommended procedure will not seriously damage the planet*.

The paint in the can itself might be *environment-friendly*, if it has so much lead, so much tin, so much phosphorous, and so on. This here means *This product will not damage the environment.* (Well, 'not any more than we're legally permitted to' at least.)

The former is for a process of some sort, and the latter, for a product where no further assembly or DIY or priming is involved; you simply open and consume (use up) the contents.

"Made using environmentally-friendly manufacturing practices" is one way to standardize, but it's sometimes inconvenient to print lengthy mandatories on a small packaging area.Also, this sometimes says nothing of the product itself, in which case it might turn out that the actual import is "this product contains an alarming abundance of ozone-depleting substances, but it happens to be manufactured using an approved process in a state-of-the-art setup that conforms to the European standard."

In some cases it's also sometimes tough to take a call on which is more correct. Is an "electric car" environmentally-friendly, or is it environment-friendly? There's as much semantics in R&D as in marketing & advertising.Company A might claim the former, while Company B might object. And while the government, the companies and the scientists go about interminably to reach a consensus, marketing and Q3 targets cannot wait. So, a convenient *eco-friendly* is used instead. This doesn't make it explicit if it means ecologically-friendly, or ecology-friendly, so the guys in legal like it. It's also shorter, so adland likes it.Run with it.

Between the two usages, *environmentally-friendly* carries the greater risk of morphing into *This improves the environment*, while *environment-friendly* just may or may not be factual, where provable.

Then again, with a product like packaged organic compost for your garden, you could use either, or perhaps even both, and it'd still ring/be true.

The contextual relevance of *when* either usage becomes significant with respect to a product also differs with different product categories - for a can of paint, it might be when the spraying is being done, for a battery it might be when after it runs out of juice and is discarded. For a synthetic food product, it might be when you're actually eating it *as well as after you've eaten it*. and so on.

Speaking for myself, I'd any day prefer a battery that claims to be *environment-friendly*, not *environmentally-friendly*.

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are omitted when the phrasal adjective begins with an adverb ending in *-ly*:

- professionally typed letter
- environmentally friendly products

Here, the *-ly* adverbs necessarily modify the adjectives that follow them, so a connecting hyphen is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

All I can think of (which might be far from what you want to know, but I hope not) are the sentences we learned in school:

He is a careful driver

vs

He drives carefully

So, can we bring that further and say:

We take care of the environment

vs

We are environmentally friendly

Can't explain it, but it sounds like maybe that could be part of the reason? :)

Comment: I don't recall being taught anything about those two sentences, and to be honest I don't distinguish them apart slightly favouring the first form. Were you taught some subtle difference between the alternatives, that sheds light on my question?

Comment: I am not sure if it sheds any light, because I can't show you the rules on it. But the difference is that "He is a careful driver" tells us something about the driver, while "he drives carefully" tells us something about the driving. But still, I have trouble relating it completely to your example. Hopefully someone else can. And if not I apologise. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Let's try something related to the [Normalized Google Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance) :)

["Enviroment Friendly"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22environment%20friendly%22) - 6,400,000 results

["Environmentally Friendly"](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%22environmentally+friendly%22&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d6a9f1ad724581c8) - 23,000,000 results

["Environment-Friendly"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22environment-friendly%22&hl=en&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=) - 6,430,000 results

["Environmentally-Friendly"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22environmentally-friendly%22&hl=en&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=) - 23,100,000 results

and the winner is ...

Comment: I don't know why you posted this. I already pointed out in my question that "the 'allies' massively outnumber" the uninflected form. I'm not asking for confirmation of that fact, I'm asking *why* it is so - particularly given that other *-friendly* coinages just use the uninflected noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm being downvoted because I'm supplying the numbers? hmmm

Comment: @pageman: I certainly didn't downvote *because* you supplied the numbers. In general I wish people would do this more often, though I do think Google hits should be taken with an even bigger pince of salt than their NGrams. No, I downvoted because, as I'd have thought my last sentence in OP makes clear, I was looking for a *reason*, not more details about the known facts. Having said that, please believe that I appreciate any response at all, even if I feel compelled to downvote in the interests of the site as a whole.

Comment: @FumbleFingers good point! :) I did preface it with "Normalized Google Distance" - I could have cited "Kolmogorov Complexity" as a reason and then linked to: http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00002784/01/tkde06.pdf but this is not SO! ;)

Comment: @pageman: That's all very interesting, but it's really about the 'connectedness' of *any* pair/group of words. In this case we're dealing with *pre-defined* relationships, in that all four permutations do actually occur as 'stock phrases'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers exactly. that's why I qualified it with "something related to" ;)